# How to force a column of a Handson table jquery to be noneditable?

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a 8 rows and two columns table. I need only the second column to be editable. The first column should be non editable (read only)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#example1").handsontable({
    startRows: 8,
    startCols: 2,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    fillHandle: true
  });
```

Is there such an option in handsontable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handsontable` allows you to specify a column that will be read only:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#example1").handsontable({
    data: getCarData(),
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: ["Car", "Year", "Chassis color", "Bumper color"],
    columns: [
      {
        data: "car",
        readOnly: true
      },
      {
        data: "year"
      },
      {
        data: "chassis"
      },
      {
        data: "bumper"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

For more info, reference the [handsontable docs](http://handsontable.com/demo/readonly.html#columns).